# Groovy check array contains string does not work identically with literal string and concat string

Tags: arrays, string, jenkins, groovy

When you check a literal string within a list or array, it works well. 
But when you check a concat string within a list or array, it returns incorrect result.

And when compare the literal string and concat string directly, they are considered identical.

I failed at Jenkins pipeline with these code and I was tried on Groovy 1.8.9 directly, the result was the same.

In this code, `issue_file = "issue-${signal_dc_key}.json"`, then `contains` returns `false`

```
def issued_list = ["names":["issue-something-DC-VV.json","issue-else-DC-VV.json"]]

            def signal_dc_key = "something-DC-VV"
            def issue_file = "issue-${signal_dc_key}.json"
            println issue_file                                         // issue-something-DC-VV.json
            println issue_file == "issue-something-DC-VV.json"                  // true
            println issue_file == "issue-${signal_dc_key}.json"                 // true
            println issued_list["names"].contains("${issue_file}")              // false
            println issued_list["names"].contains(issue_file)                   // false
            println issued_list["names"].contains("issue-something-DC-VV.json")   // true
```

In this code, `issue_file = "issue-something-DC-VV.json"`, `contains` returns `true`.

```
def issued_list = ["names":["issue-something-DC-VV.json","issue-else-DC-VV.json"]]
            def signal_dc_key = "something-DC-VV"
            def issue_file = "issue-something-DC-VV.json"
            println issue_file                                         // issue-something-DC-VV.json
            println issue_file == "issue-something-DC-VV.json"                 // true
            println issue_file == "issue-${signal_dc_key}.json"                  // true
            println issued_list["names"].contains("${issue_file}")              // false
            println issued_list["names"].contains(issue_file)                   // true
            println issued_list["names"].contains("issue-something-DC-VV.json")   // true
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like got fixed by changing this line

```
def issue_file = "issue-${signal_dc_key}.json"
```

to

```
def issue_file = new String("issue-${signal_dc_key}.json" )
```

But `new String` is NOT permitted in Jenkins.

Thanks to Michael Rutherfurd's comment, `toString()` works and is permitted in Jenkins.

```
def issue_file = "issue-${signal_dc_key}.json".toString()
```

Comment: `new String` is not permitted in Jenkins.  What a pity.
`
[Pipeline] // script
Error when executing failure post condition:
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.lang.String java.lang.String
`

Comment: Is toString() allowed i.e. def issue_file = "issue-${signal_dc_key}.json".toString()

Comment: Cool! Thank you  Michael Rutherfurd . `toString()` works and is permitted in Jenkins.

Comment: `.toString()` really helped! Thanks @MichaelRutherfurd. @David Young, please mark this answer as accepted (gray check box under voting buttons should work for you). It's OK to accept your own answer. So others will know the problem is solved.